# What's the difference between `MapBase` and `MapMixin` in terms of coding my own Map class?

Tags: flutter, dictionary, dart, extends, implements

I want to code my own `Map` class. `MapBase` and `MapMixin` have similar documentations. Which one should I use to code my own `Map` class? And why?

I understand `MapBase` has more functions because it implements `MapMixin`. However, the functions in `MapBase` don't seem to be important because all of its functions are `static`.

```dart
...
/// A basic `Map` class can be implemented by extending this class and
/// implementing `keys`, `operator[]`, `operator[]=`, `remove` and `clear`.
/// The remaining operations are implemented in terms of these five.
...
abstract class MapBase<K, V> extends MapMixin<K, V> {
```

```dart
...
/// A basic `Map` class can be implemented by mixin in this class and
/// implementing `keys`, `operator[]`, `operator[]=`, `remove` and `clear`.
/// The remaining operations are implemented in terms of these five.
...
abstract class MapMixin<K, V> implements Map<K, V> {
```

Comment: Does not really matter. The advantage with the mixin is that you can include multiple mixins in your class where you can only extend from one class.

Comment: @julemand101 – yup! Make this an answer! Get the karma!

Comment: @KevinMoore Done. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not really matter. The advantage with the mixin is that you can include multiple mixins in your class where you can only extend from one class.

Comment: We had `MapBase` before we had `minin` support in the language. One could effectively consider `MapBase` deprecated...ish.